# Javascript - Dynamically load a fragment of HTML and run script

Tags: javascript, init

I'm building a webpage and I want to re-use some HTML I have elsewhere on my website. The page I am building (`index.html`) can dynamically get and insert the HTML I want (`existing.html`) using `XMLHttpRequest`. However, the HTML I want to get is populated by some Javscript. That Javascript is not being executed when I load it into my new page:

index.html:

```
<html>

    <head>
        <script type = "text/javascript">
            ... //use XMLHttpRequest to load existing.html
            initExistingHTML(); //this is function which populates loaded HTML, is not executed
        </script>
    </head>    

<html>
```

existing.html:

```
<div>
    <script type = "text/javascript">
        function initExistingHTML() {
           ... // do some stuff
        }
    </script>
</div>
```

How can I load `existing.html` and run the script which populates it?

Answer (score 0):

Once the page has loaded, add in `existing.html` via `innerHTML`. Rather than calling its functions, just let `existing.html`'s code execute, which will do the same as if it were in the `onload` section.

EDIT: Or, you could just correct that typo you have. `initExistingHTML` != `initExistingHtml`.
lol

Comment: This is what I thought I was doing, could you provide an example of how to achieve this?

Comment: It's easy, man. Just put the code you have in initExistingHTML naked in the script tag. Also, your case is different!

Comment: Sorry, case error (now corrected) was due to me typing a representative example and now copy/pasting the actual code. I don't want to copy the code over because creates duplication.

Comment: Oh, OK. So your real code is correct. Well, take my advice and use bare code instead of functions when you want to insert something. You have no way of knowing when code is initialized, thus no way of calling the function.